# Remove duplicate words, but retain duplicate numbers in sentence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to remove duplicate words many sentence, but without removing single or double digit numbers.

I previously used the following to remove duplicates, whilst retaining order, but this removes single repeating numbers.

```
df['reporting_name'] = df['reporting_name'].str.split().apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys() if x is not None else None).str.join(' ')
```

So I imagine I need some regex to either split where a word is followed by a number (incl. whitespace), something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/5UL4D8/1). 
Or perhaps there is another generic solution.

**Input**

```
"East Zone Mbc26 East Zone 1 2nd S11B Smds Smoke Damper 1 Status"
"GF Command Room 1 Unit 1 Flow Temperature Temperature"
```

**Expected output**

```
"East Zone Mbc26 Zone 1 2nd S11B Smds Smoke Damper 1 Status"
"GF Command Room 1 Unit 1 Flow Temperature"
```

Duplicate words are removed, numbers are kept and the order of words is maintained.

When a word has an identifier and is a duplicate, such as "Zone 1", then retain both "Zone" and "Zone 1".

Comment: Why do you keep **first** `East` and **second** `Zone`?

Comment: Do you want to do this for a string?

Comment: What about 3-or-more-digit numbers? Floats? In `Damper 2 Status` the output has changed the number. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Toto, I should have explained, I wish to retain the Zone identifier, in this case 1. So when an identifier is available, both can stay.

Comment: @Reti43, That was indeed a typo, the whole sentence is a string, no floats will exist in the names.

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, yes they are strings. Edited this.

Comment: The question is why do you expect `East Mbc26 Zone` and not `East Zone Mbc26`?

Comment: @Toto, if a word has an identifier, such as a 1 behind Zone, then retain both Zone 1 and Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if you want to keep the first occurence of every non digit word. You can always trick the condition to force having max two digits.

```
def cleanup(s):
    words = set()
    for (word, nextword) in zip(s.split(), s.split()[1:] + [None]):
        if word.isdigit():
            yield word
            continue
        if not word in words:
            words.add(word)
            yield word
        elif nextword and nextword.isdigit():
            yield word


print ' '.join(cleanup("East Zone Mbc26 East Zone 1 2nd S11B Smds Smoke Damper 1 Status"))
print ' '.join(cleanup("GF Command Room 1 Unit 1 Flow Temperature Temperature"))
```

**Output**

```
East Zone Mbc26 Zone 1 2nd S11B Smds Smoke Damper 1 Status
GF Command Room 1 Unit 1 Flow Temperature
```

Comment: Instead of all that try-except, you can simply do `word.isdigit()`.

Comment: I should have been more explicit, I actually wish to retain both Zone 1 and Zone in the first sentence, otherwise that 1 may be misinterpreted. So whenever there is an identifier after a duplicated word, retain both.